# Unix IPC in the order of usage?

Tags: unix, ipc, pipe, shared-memory, semaphore

A bit of a background first: 
I'm a relative newbie in unix systems programming. Right now I'm reading a bunch on unix network and system programming through the Rich. Stevens books. I'm working my way through pipes, FIFOS, Posix and System V message queues, semaphores, shared memory, SUN RPC etc.

Now to the question:
Though I'm enjoying it all but getting to know everything in a short span is a little challenging especially as I do it beyond my working hours...So can't help but question myself in terms of how relevant all these still are, especially since I'm reading these books well over 10+ years since they were first written.

Don't get me wrong, I still think that probably most of these concepts will stay around forever, **but I'd like to know which of these IPC is the most prevalent or popular of them all and is still very relevant?** This way I could narrow down and concentrate more on things which are more "in use" so to speak.

[In short, I'd like to know which of the IPC are very common and popular and which ones are sorta not used that much anymore.]

Thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 0):

In vendor production code, ignoring doors (I'm on Solaris largely), most of the IPC methods are still used commonly.  For example, on Solaris, oracle products make massive use of sockets, pipes, sempahores, shared memory. Our CIS app uses message queues, RPC's in addition to the above.

If you compare Michael Kerrisk (2009) 'The Linux Programming Interface' to Stevens, you will see that there is not much change in IPC from the last version (I have)  of Stevens/Rago  and Kerrisk.  -- minus Linux-isms.
Linux has added features.

Keep on doing what you are doing.